# Getting an object instead of a boolean value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an async function that checks the permission status in a device.
This is the function:

```
notificationsAllowed = async () => {
    const allowed = await requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound']).then((res) => {
        if (res.status == "granted") {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });

    return allowed;
}
```

`allowed` is `boolean`, but when I try to use this function (for example, to set a switch to true or false) I get an object for some reason.
This is how I try to use it:

```
const allowed = NotificationsManager.getInstance().notificationsAllowed().then((res) => {
    return res;
});

const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(allowed);
```

It seems like allowed is of type `Promise<boolean>` but I can't use async await because it is inside a functional component.

Comment: Instead of `return res;` do `setIsEnabled(res)` and use `useState(false)` or whatever a reasonable default would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `useEffect` for something like this.

```
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    NotificationsManager.getInstance().notificationsAllowed().then((res) => {
        setIsEnabled(res);
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: What is `useEffect()`?  What is `setIsEnabled()`?  Where are you getting these functions from?

Comment: Those are React things. OP didn't tag their post with React, but it's pretty clearly about that if you know React at all, and OP should recognize the `useEffect` (and has the `setIsEnabled` already). Basically the `useEffect` is a way to call a function after renders (with the `[]` as the second param called only once) and the `setIsEnabled` is a setter for the state, received from the `useState`, which lets you save state between renders.

Comment: @tuomokar I've never used React, thanks for answering the question in a way that works the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how `async` functions or `await` work.  Normally, with `Promises` (like `requestNotifications`), you run it, it does its work in the background and then it runs the `.then()` function when it's done (at some point in the future).

`await` does what it says, and *waits* for the `Promise` to resolve/finish before continuing on.  You don't need `.then()` here, since you are waiting for it to finish in a different way.

```
notificationsAllowed = async () => {
    const allowed = await requestNotifications(['alert', 'sound']);
    return allowed.status === "granted"
};
```

But now `notificationsAllowed` is an `async` function.  So you either need to use `.then()` which runs it in the background or use `await` to wait for `notificationsAllowed` to complete.

```
const allowed = await NotificationsManager.getInstance().notificationsAllowed();
const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(allowed);
```

Or you need to use a callback, which will run at some point in the future and not let you *return* a value:

```
NotificationsManager.getInstance().notificationsAllowed().then(allowed => {
    const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(allowed);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I That explanation was great and now this async/await thing is clearer. Thank you so much!

Comment: It's a good explanation, but neither of those solutions is something you should do with React (which the code in the OP uses). Hooks must never run conditionally and they must run in the same order every time. Because of that they can't be called asynchronously. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html for further info.

Comment: @tuomokar I didn't know React was being used here, the OP never said that.

Comment: Yeah it's not tagged with it unfortunately.